# Controlling air pressure solenoid

Tags: solenoid, solenoid-valve

I am needing to create a system which will control air pressure (0-50psi). I have found what I'm thinking I need [here](https://www.zoro.com/aro-solenoid-air-control-valve-18-in-12vdc-p251ss-012-d/i/G1419713/). It is a solenoid air control valve which uses 12vdc. The specs state that the device has a pressure range from 0 - 120psi. How would I control the flow of that device? Would I be limiting the voltage? Or is the device I have listed only on-off all or nothing? If it is, what type of device can be used to variably control an air pressure between 0 and 50psi?

**--Edit--**

What I am attempting to do is create an [electronic boost controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_controller#Electronic_boost_control) for a turbocharged vehicle using an arduino for a controller.

A quick and dirty explanation on how a boost controller works: Turbo is regulated via wastegate actuator. If you have an 8psi wastegate actuator that means that when the intake system reaches 8psi, the wastegate will open and any exhaust pressure that would spool the turbo past 8psi bypasses the turbine wheel straight into the exhaust system. Boost controllers allow you to limit the amount of pressure going to the wastegate actuator. Therefore if you have an 8 pound wastegate, but want to run 12psi of boost you dial your controller in so that 12psi on the intake side equals 8psi on the wastegate side.

What I am looking for is a device which can be electronically controlled to (and this is where I'm not sure on the terminology so forgive me) "regulate" the amount of pressure that is going to the wastegate actuator, as well as withstand temperatures of around 200-220 degrees fahrenheit.

[Picture of how a manual boost controller functions](http://www.enginebasics.com/Advanced%20Engine%20Tuning/Images/boost%20controller%205.jpg)

Comment: What does the data sheet say? If it hasn't got a data sheet don't buy it.

Comment: That's an on/off valve, like a switch but for air. The last time I used an electronically controllable air-pressure regulator it was a significantly more complicated multi-port device with a 0-10V control input.

Comment: You are looking at a relatively sophisticated beast.  The search below will show you typical pictures that will probably link to datasheets or vendors.  -  https://www.google.com/search?q=electronic+pressure+regulator&tbm=isch

Comment: @null: You need to add context to your question. There is no clue in it regarding the application which, according to a link buried in the comments, is internal combustion engine turbo-charger. You are confusing pneumatic pressure and pneumatic flow. You need to straighten out your thinking and do an edit with a specification.

Comment: @Transistor I have edited my question to be more specific. I'm a bit confused on the difference between pneumatic pressure/flow. Maybe after reading my edit you can set me straight.

Comment: @null: That's better. Turbo isn't my area, I'm afraid. A couple of pointers: (1) By 8 pounds do you mean 8 psi? (A pressure rather than a weight.) (2) You seem to be looking for an electrically controlled variable pressure relief valve. i.e., it's going to vent above a set pressure. (3) You might want to mention operating temperature in your specification.

Comment: @Transistor: I have updated my question to say psi vs pounds, and added a temperature range. Thanks for looking this over :)

Comment: You cannot be the only guy wanting to do this.  Take inspiration from others before you.  Look at  the following images and see if something looks like a useful contender. If you have followed about 30 links and no further inspiration then ask here again, This is for general electronics not niche market hot-rodding so others will have better answers than this group can offer.  Good luck.  -  https://www.google.com/search?q=adjustable+turbo+boost+bypass+valve&tbm=isch

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the pressure you can look for a **pressure controller** such as the one pictured below which controls absolute (rather than gauge) pressure.

[image]

Or a **digital pressure regulator** (often called an **I/P transducer** because they accept a 4-20mA current (I) and control the (P) pressure).

[image]

There are also **proportional flow valves** that provide a controlled flow depending on the input signal.

Expect to pay *at least* an order of magnitude more for this kind of product than a simple on/off solenoid valve (and there are some that cost $thousands).

Answer (score 0):

Solenoid valves are ON-OFF devices.  The rating of 0-120 psi refers to the operating range of the device, there is no way to have variable control.  Pneumatic control isn't my area of expertise, but I've seen servo-controlled ball-valves, which may be of use to you.  Specifying your intended application may help identify a solution.

Comment: I recently started playing with an arduino and was going to try my hand at building a simple boost controller: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_controller

Comment: Definitely out of my area of knowledge! Hopefully someone can recommend a suitable control system.

Comment: I'm liking the idea of the servo controlled ball valve. We used to make manual controllers this way back in the day, only we used a threaded bolt to control the valve vs an electrical servo. Worth looking into at least. Appreciate the answer :)

Comment: @nullReference - Servo controlled ball valve is going to be mainly controlling flow rate and not pressure. A pressure regulator in general principle is a flow controlled valve that uses a pressure detect feedback to control the valve.

Answer (score 0):

With a pressure sensor feedback and a 5A LDO ADJ regulator you can regulate the solenoid current to maintain pressure a fixed flow rate

Since this is like controlling the voltage with a transistor , the output voltage  will be highly dependant on current flow and thus poor pressure load regulation.

For better control you need a stepper controlled lead screw pressure valve with a pressure sensor for feedback and limit sensors.